# Determining next selection menu by previous selection

Tags: php, html, post, drop-down-menu

I have 3 select drop downs which I want when the first one selected, the second shows up, and when the second is selected, the third one shows up, by using `if(isset($_post[first_one]))` and for the third one using `if(isset($_post[second_one]))`

**SQL:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sp_meeting_log ";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql);
```

**PHP/HTML:**

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:300px; left:500px;">
    <form method="post">
        <p>Choose:</p>
        <!--Get all orgs ,forums ,Users data available for admin-->
        //select the first
        <select style="display:inline-block;" name="org">
            <option value="All Orgs">All Orgs</option>
            //first drop down info release
            <?php
            if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "<table><tr><th>orgID</th><th>orgName</th></tr>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<option>" .$row["orgID"]." /".$row["orgName"]."</option>";
                }

                echo "</table>";
            } else {
                echo "0 results";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <select style="display:inline-block;" name="forum">
            <option value="forum1"><h5>All Forums</h5></option>
            <?php
            // if the first dropdown post set
            if(isset($_POST['org'])){  
                $result2 = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<table><tr><th>forumID</th><th>forumName</th></tr>";
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<option>".$row["forumID"]." / ".$row["forumName"]."</option>";
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
                } else {
                    echo "0 results";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        //select the second
        <select style="display:inline-block;" name="user">
            <option><h5>All Users</h5></option>
            <?php
            // if the second drop down is set
            if(isset($_POST['forum'])){
                $result3 = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
                    echo "<table><tr><th>userID</th><th>username</th></tr>";
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
                        echo "<option>".$row["userID"]." / ".$row["username"]. "</option>";
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
                } else {

                echo "0 results";
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: when i post the first one,still the second and third it doesnt showed up

Comment: @Rasclatt tnx dude for correction but i am not writting paper or academic stuffs,instead of correcting my writting errors ,find out the way to solve this issue,tnx

Comment: Your code formatting is a courtesy to others who are trying to help you figure out a solution to your problem. When it's difficult to read a script, people have a tendency to skip over your question because it's not worth the hassle of trying to muddle through it and your question title itself did not describe your problem very concisely. It is also a general *duty* to fix formatting (and other issues with content) as a user of SO, especially if the formatting is as atrocious as yours was.

Comment: As for your question, use ajax, makes more sense than reloading the page.

Comment: @Rasclatt tnx buddy,actually i stopped in this question long ago,and i m not much familiar with ajax ,and lack of time,could you tell me how to use ajax for this problem?

Comment: @Rasclatt ,i found this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp but,i am using highcharts ,and the purpose to get these 3 rows ,is to bring the data into highcharts,if i use ajax ,how is possible to change ajax variable to php variable for passing to mysql?

Comment: Yes, your html page loads up the first dropdown. On change, you have ajax hit a page that takes the value of the dropdown and runs an sql. That sql then would populate an empty container, like a div or span with a dropdown. Then on change of that, it does the same thing as the first. You need two pages to do this ideally

Comment: so if i m not wrong you mean i can use the same methos i have but with 2 separate php pages which handle the  $result = $conn->query($sql);   ?

Comment: Yes, dropdown one would be on your load page, then your other two could be contained on your second page which is called by the first. If you use jQuery you could use `$('#dropdown_zone_1').html(response);` with `response` being what is returned from success of the ajax and would drop it into a spot like `<div id="dropdown_zone_1"></div>`

Comment: by the method u mentioned the current page which showing the dropdowns will be reload to show the second and third drop downs?  how about my method which i used "post" is that reload my page as well? which one u recomment  ,post,ajax or jquery dropdown zone? ( i dont want my current page reload,only by choosing the first one ,the second,and using second,the third will be shown

Comment: ajax and the jQuery dropdown zone are the same. I will post a quick answer so you can try it.

Comment: u can see this: on the top left i tried exactly the same w3school written and gives answer,but how to bring it to drop downs?http://www.mrkhish.com/EndUserMetrics/Analysis/passdate/test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially this is what the idea is. You want page one to just fetch from page two and post the result back to page one into the correct spots:

**page1.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form>
    <label>Org
        <select id="org" name="org">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <!-- This is where the forum html will drop into after ajax runs -->
    <div id="forum"></div>
    <!-- This is where the user html will drop into after ajax runs -->
    <div id="user"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // On change of a select menu
        $(this).on('change','select',function(e){
            // Assign selection
            var thisSelect  =   $(this);
            // Get the id name, this will tell page two
            //  what it's receiving
            var sendType    =   thisSelect.attr('id');
            // Get the actual value of the selection 
            var sendVal     =   thisSelect.val();
            // Create essentially a POST
            var sendData    =   { field: sendType, value: sendVal };
            $.ajax({
                // Send to page 2
                url : '/page2.php',
                // Use post method
                type: "POST",
                // Use post data from above
                data : sendData,
                // This is what will run on success
                success:function(response){
                    // Parse the json coming back for placement
                    var jSon    =   JSON.parse(response);
                    // Save the correct html into the correct drop spot
                    $('#'+jSon.type).html(jSon.html);
                },
                error: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**page2.php**

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $data   =   '';
    ob_start();
    if(isset($_POST['field'])) {
        if($_POST['field'] == 'org') {
            $type   =   'forum';
?>
    <label>Forum
        <select id="forum" name="forum">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </label>
<?php
    }
    elseif($_POST['field'] == 'forum') {
        $type   =   'user';
?>
    <label>user
        <select id="user" name="user">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </label>
<?php   }
        $data   =   ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        die(json_encode(array('type'=>$type,'html'=>$data)));
    }

    die(json_encode(array('type'=>'error','html'=>false)));
}
```